# Create RSA keys with good SYNTAX

Tags: javascript, cryptography, key, rsa, public

How can I generate proper **RSA** keyfiles with correct syntax? Best would be soluction in javascript.

I have already generated numbers for **512bit** key:

**e =** `00065537`

**d =** `2a3ff2f501835d7d0f7ccad34265525b0c91f800fc252324e4bb5668392ba55a65d812d658b7065725c259a12115918dbdbbea6cead9225a91c3fcc6b43f1cb3`

**m =** `4bb26cf2e1e1cdbbf78f89a60d5af5cf094a7216f9fe2d0e2288dc14e6005e0b6de46dc38f0e92b8b3281e9f1cf87257fb54bff579907e8a3c114133b74cb815`

Comment: There is no such thing as an "RSA keyfile". You must specify the standard, and then you must first try yourself.

Comment: 512 bits is far to short for basically any usage scenario. Use 2048 bits at least. Also, you have to use a cryptographically secure random number generator to generate the key. Lastly, what is `m`? Is that the RSA modulus, i.e. n=pq for two primes p,q?

Comment: Oh, and are you sure all these numbers are in base 16? I guess e=2^16+1=65537 in base 10.

Comment: @Perseids: Oddly enough, e is 0x65537. That e works, but e=2^16 + 1 doesn't.

Comment: @GregS: You mean $(x^e)^d=x\mod m$ for the $x$ you tried only if you assume $e$ to be 0x65537 ?

Comment: @GregS okay ^^. This questions looks dead anyway :/